# How do I envoke npm remotely via ssh

Tags: bash, ssh, npm

I have `nodejs` installed on a remote machine via `nvm`.  What nvm does is it adds something to the bottom end of .bashrc to setup so when .bashrc is invoked it adds the particular version of nodes `bin` directory on to the path.

I would like to run `npm ci` in a script I run remotely which has has the following line

`ssh agmb 'cd ~/xxxx && npm ci'`, but it always replies npm not found. (agmb is an entry in my .ssh/config file which specifies the user and host I want to connect to - I can actually connect into the account with a simple ssh agmb).

Assuming the .bashrc is maybe not being sourced I've tried this

`ssh -t agmb 'source ~/.bashrc && env'`  but this shows path not having been expanded at all.

How can I run npm via ssh?

Comment: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/820517/bashrc-at-ssh-login

Comment: @FrankThomas I've been through a load of answers like that, but as you can see, I am sourcing the file directly and it still doesn't appear to work